# Forçar redirecionamento de url com htaccess com senha

Tags: htaccess, url

preciso testar um site que estou criando e para isso vou deixar que algumas pessoas o acessem, ocorre que quero somente deixar acesso a uma url especifica que abre o login do site.

EX:http://xxxxxx.net/xxxxxx/xxxxx/login.php

Qualquer outra forma deve ficar bloqueada.

preciso de ajuda pra criar o htaccess disso.

Valeu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bem depende do Servidor Web, se for o `Apache` você pode por estas configurações no seu `VHOST`:

```
 <Directory "/usr/local/apache2/htdocs/seusite.com/">
      Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
      Order allow,deny
      Allow from all
 </Directory>

 <Location "/seusite.com/restrito">
      Options +Indexes
      DirectoryIndex none

      AuthName "Acesso Restrito"
      AuthType Basic

      # Você pode usar o programa htaccess para criar o banco de dados de senha:
      #   htpasswd -c "/usr/local/apache2/auth/user.htpasswd" admin
      AuthUserFile "/usr/local/apache2/auth/user.htpasswd"

      # Só pode acessar se for usuário autenticado
      Require valid-user

      # Redireciona a Pessoa se errar a autenticacao
      ErrorDocument 401 "<html><meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;url=/index.html\"></html>"
      # Redireciona a Pessoa se for usuário autenticado
      Redirect permanent /restrito http://seusite.com/cpanel
 </Location>
```

Depois só criar uma pasta no `ServerRoot` chamado `auth` e por permissões adequadas:

```
# mkdir -p /usr/local/apache2/auth
# htpasswd -c "/usr/local/apache2/auth/user.htpasswd" admin
# chown root:www-data -R /usr/local/apache2/auth/user.htpasswd
# chmod 640 /usr/local/apache2/auth/user.htpasswd
```

A ideia é que o `Apache` ler linha a linha e em ordem, mas se não quiser a autenticação é só usar o `Redirect`.

Comment: Obrigado amigo pela resposta bem completa, seria apenas um teste usando o wamp (windows). Não seria mais fácil fazer isso no htaccess?

Answer (score 3):

Crie um arquivo chamado ".htpasswd".

<sub>O nome pode ser qualquer um que lhe convier, não necessariamente ".htpasswd".</sub>

Cole isso dentro do ".htpasswd":

```
login:$apr1$pfIh.j7l$Zlqiecx1ZoYfEoUn1QVA50
```

"**login**" é o usuário

"**$apr1$pfIh.j7l$Zlqiecx1ZoYfEoUn1QVA50**" é uma string encriptada. A senha é "pass".

No htaccess, adicione:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Password Protected Area"
AuthUserFile /caminho/absoluto/do/arquivo/.htpasswd
Require valid-user
```

Isso é o suficiente para começar a usar.

Para gerar o password encriptado, há centenas de sites como esse: http://www.htaccesstools.com/htpasswd-generator/. Basta procurar no google "htaccess password generator" ou você mesmo pode gerar sem uso de internet.

<sub>*Até aqui abordamos de forma superficial. Caso queira saber mais sobre o assunto, continue com a leitura abaixo.</sub>

## Gerando senha

Para ambiente Windows, no diretório de instalação do Apache, na pasta "bin", encontrará o executável "htpasswd.exe". Pelo CMD do Windows, acesse a pasta desse arquivo, exemplo

```
cd C:\Apache\httpd-2.4.20-win64-VC14\bin
```

<sub>*O local exato varia de acordo com a instalação no seu sistema.</sub>

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A senha pode possuir tipos diferentes de encriptação e inclusive pode ser gerada como `plain/text`, ou seja, em "texto plano", sem encriptação. O padrão é MD5. Note que o tipo de senha escolhido afeta o parâmetro `AuthType`, portanto, caso encripte a senha com outro formato como o crypt, defina o `AuthType` equivalente a encriptação utilizada. Consulte a documentação: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/auth.html

<sub>*Para gerar a senha em outros ambientes como linux e mac, segue a mesma lógica. Apenas modificará o caminho do executável e alguns recursos.</sub>

## Dicas de segurança

O caminho do arquivo .htpasswd deve estar num local privado, sem acesso público.

Exemplo, se o index do site estiver em c:/www/site/index.php, coloque o arquivo numa pasta fora da pasta pública

Como NÃO fazer:

```
c:/www/site/.htpasswd
```

Desse modo, terceiros podem fazer download do arquivo da senha. Por isso, evite colocar num local de acesso público

Sugestão de onde colocar:

```
c:/www/.htpasswd
```

## Nomenclatura do arquivo de senha

O nome padrão é .htpasswd pois a instalação padrão do Apache verifica se esse arquivo existe e caso exista, ele é bloqueado de acesso externo caso esteja num diretório público. Isso é para os casos onde houver um descuido e deixar o arquivo com acesso público.

Apesar disso, não confie plenamente, pois nem todos os ambientes podem possuir a mesmo regra por padrão. Por via das dúvidas, deixe o arquivo fora da pasta pública.

Para mais detalhes sobre o assunto, leia a documentação: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/programs/htpasswd.html#examples

## Permitir arquivos e diretórios específicos

Para permitir acesso livre a subdiretórios ou arquivos específicos, adicione a regra baseada na URI:

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI "(/caminho/completo/do/diretorio1/)$"         allow
SetEnvIf Request_URI "(/caminho/completo/do/diretorio2/)$"         allow
SetEnvIf Request_URI "(/caminho/completo/do/diretorio3/)$"         allow
SetEnvIf Request_URI "(/caminho/completo/aquivo/especifico\.php)$"             allow
Order allow,deny
Allow from env=allow
Satisfy any
```

## Uma alternativa usando somente PHP

```
if (
    !isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'], $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW'])
    || $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'] !== 'login'
    || $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW'] !== 'pass'
) {
        header('WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="Enter username and password."');
        header('Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8');
        echo 'Restricted Area'; exit;
}
```

Nesse caso teria que adicionar o script em todas as páginas que deseja bloquear com a senha.

Se o seu sistema possuir um roteador, por exemplo, então bastaria apenas adicionar o código no roteador, normalmente o "index.php".

## Contra

Outros arquivos como imagens, acesso a diretórios, etc, por fim, tudo que não for PHP e não possui o script, terá acesso livre.

Apesar disso, para um propósito geral como manter o site bloqueado de acesso público enquanto está em desenvolvimento ou manutenção, é o suficiente.

## Pró

O ponto contra pode ser também um ponto positivo, pois como os arquivos de imagens estão com acesso livre, mecanismos de busca como google ainda poderão indexar imagens enquanto o sistema está numa manutenção temporária, por exemplo. Evitando, assim, perder rankeamento e indexações das imagens enquanto o site está bloqueado.

É também mais flexível, pois poderá criar as condições diretamente com o PHP, onde é mais fácil de lidar. No seu caso, você quer permitir acesso livre ao arquivo login.php. Então bastaria criar uma condicional que verifica qual o nome do arquivo que está em execução e gerar as condições que desejar.

Comment: Valeu Daniel, muito bom seu tutorial cara. Mas to com uma duvida aqui. O método básico que vc colocou logo no começo funcionou perfeito, mas eu quero que peça senha só na raiz (pasta www) para que as pessoas não vejam minha pagina do wamp e as pastas listadas, acima disso, no caminho para o meu site, os usuários podem acessar sem senha. Entendeu?

Comment: Nesse caso você poderia usar a alternativa com PHP, se possível. Se não for possível, acredito que basta definir a regra para não bloquear subdiretórios. Adicionei exemplo na resposta "Permitir arquivos e diretórios específicos"

Comment: Muito obrigado pelo help cara!!

Answer (score 2):

Não acho bom criar um arquivo htaccess e nele ter o usuário e suas configurações, depois só copiar e colar nas pastas que deseja bloquear, porque a um custo de processamento do Servidor Web para procurar estes arquivos e depois mascarar eles para não serem vistos, baixados ou editados pelos clientes mas se centralizar eles numa única pasta e dele configurar na Vhosts do site além de fica mais semântico,  poupa memória e vejo que é uma prática muito boa aplicado por profissionais de TI.

No Wamp tem como mas é meio complicado já que ele tem muitos diretórios escondendo o Apache aconselho o `Ampps` por ter um diretório simples e facil mas enfim o ServerRoot fica em `C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.x`, nela vai ter às principais pastas:

- **\bin** - binaries (apachectl) - Executaveis
- **\conf\httpd.conf** - Apache Config File
- **\conf\extra** - Other Config Files
- **C:\wamp\www** - DocumentRoot

Abre o `Prompt de Comando` em `ServerRoot` usando o SHIPT(Direito)+Botão Auxiliar do Mouse e segue os Comandos:

```
cd C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.x
md auth

cd bin\
dir ht*

htpasswd -c "..\auth\user.htpasswd" admin
exit
```

Aqui vai criar uma pasta que se chama `auth` e depois adicionar um `htaccess` tipo `basic`, agora é só entrar neste arquivo `\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf` com seu editor favorito editar a seguinte linha:

```
    # Raiz do Site
    DocumentRoot c:/wamp/www

    # Configuracao de Arquivos contido no Diretorio
    <Directory  "c:/wamp/www/">
        Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride All

        # So pode acessar se for usuario local pelo IP ::1 (127.0.0.1)
        Require local
    </Directory>

    # Uma pasta acima do Raiz
    <Location "/restrito">
        Options +Indexes
        DirectoryIndex none

        AuthName "Acesso Restrito"
        AuthType Basic

        # Voce pode usar o programa htaccess para criar o banco de dados de senha:
        #   htpasswd -c "..\auth\user.htpasswd" admin
        AuthUserFile "c:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.x\auth\user.htpasswd"

        # So pode acessar se for usuario autenticado
        Require valid-user

        # Redireciona a Pessoa se errar a autenticacao
        ErrorDocument 401 "<html><meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;url=/index.html\"></html>"
        # Redireciona a Pessoa se for usuario autenticado
        Redirect permanent /restrito http://localhost/cpanel
    </Location>
```

Pronto, de acordo com o Wamp o `httpd-vhost.conf` já está ativo nas Configurações do Apache o `httpd.conf`, quer dizer que pode criar outras Vhosts neste arquivo mas se por acaso não funcionar o restrito tente por então o caminho completo, não sei nesta questão do `Windows`.

Comment: Opa cara, valeu pela ajuda!